# Trying to pass object by value to constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

So I've been trying to make a test program that shows the difference between passing an object by reference, and by value.

I'd like the constructor of ClassB to take in two arguments: a reference to ClassA, and the value of ClassA.

I've been able to run the program when the constructor only takes in the reference. However, when I added the second parameter (for value of ClassA), I get the error "no matching function for call to 'ClassA::ClassA()'".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA{
    int num;

public:
    ClassA(int _num){
        num = _num;
    }

    int getNum(void){
        return num;
    }

    void addToNum(int value){
        num += value;
    }
};

class ClassB {
    ClassA * classPointer;
    ClassA classValue;

public:
    ClassB(ClassA& referencedClass, ClassA value){ // HERE I get the error
        classPointer = &referencedClass;
        classValue = value;
    }

    int getPointedNum(void){
        return classPointer->getNum();
    }

    int getValueNum(void){
        return classValue.getNum();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ClassA classA (20);
    ClassB classB (classA, classA);
    classA.addToNum(5);
    cout << "classB.getPointedNum(): " << classB.getPointedNum() << endl;
    cout << "classB.getValueNum(): " << classB.getValueNum() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody have some idea of what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: your class doesn't have a copy constructor. define one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly initialize `classValue` by calling its constructor, because you have deleted its default constructor by defining a non-default constructor.

This has to be done in the [***member initialization list***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) of the constructor, because member variables are initialized before entering the constructor body:

```
ClassB(ClassA& referencedClass, ClassA value)
: classPointer(&referencedClass), classValue(value) // member initialization list
{
    // constructor body
}
```

This will initialize `classPointer` with the value `&referencedClass` and call the default copy constructor of `ClassA` with `value`.

Comment: There is no default constructor at all. Saying a constructor is deleted, is different to saying it doesn't exist. A deleted constructor is considered for overload resolution and if it is selected then the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing corresponds to a missing initializer for the member `classValue`.

When you use

```
ClassB(ClassA& referencedClass, ClassA value) { ... }
```

the compiler tries to initialize `classValue` using the default constructor. Since there isn't one, it is not able to initialize `classValue`.

You can use:

```
ClassB(ClassA& referencedClass, ClassA value) :
    classPointer(&referencedClass_,
    classValue(value)
{
}
```